# No results are shown for custom modules in global suitecrm search

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying to add custom modules to the global search of suitecrm, but I am facing two problems, first, the modules although they are passed to the section of enabled modules in global search configuration when searching for something are not shown as modules to show results, in fact only one module is listed with results.

The other problem is that the job that is in charge of optimizing AOD indexes is completed with an error, to correct the latter I have followed the instructions in this [post](https://pgorod.github.io/Reindex-AOD/) and it works well, the error message disappeared from the log.

But I continue without being able to have results for the custom modules.

I appreciate your advice. If you need more information please just tell me

Answer (score 1):

Basic checks:

1. Go to Admin > Global Search, Is your module in Enabled modules list.
2. If No, then please drag it from the disabled modules to the enabled section.
3. If yes, then go to modules/your_module/vardef.php and verify if 'unified_search' AND 'unified_search_default_enabled' array keys are set to 'true' in the dictionary array of your custom module.

Refer to the vardefs snippet of Accounts module attached.

```
$dictionary['Account'] = array(
    'table' => 'accounts',
    'audited' => true,
    'unified_search' => true,  //Should be set to true
    'full_text_search' => true, //Should be set to true
    'unified_search_default_enabled' => true,
    'duplicate_merge' => true,
);
```

These steps will definitely fix your problem